# Trying to run an eclipse JAVA program in Sauce Labs. But getting an issue with constructor and remote webdriver.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs, remotewebdriver

Written below code to run an eclipse program in Sauce Labs. Workflow is showing an issue "The constructor Remote WebDriver(String, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined".

Still I tried to run the program then below issue came.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor RemoteWebDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined
    The constructor URL(String) is undefined at sauceprog.main(sauceprog.java:40)

CODE:

```
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;
    public class sauceprog
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException
    {
        String browser = "safari-saucelabs";
        String URL = "https://rpautomation4:27763475-7193-4984-8074-a4fe2f9982f7@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

    switch(browser.toLowerCase())
    {
    case "internetexplorer-win-saucelabs":
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
    caps.setCapability("version", "11.103");
    caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
    caps.setCapability("screenResolution", "1024x768");
    break;
    case "chrome-win-saucelabs":
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8");
    caps.setCapability("version", "69.0");
    caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
    break;
    case "firefox-win-saucelabs":
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8");
    caps.setCapability("version", "62.0");
    caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
    default: 
        System.out.println("you passed incorrect values. Please check next time");
    }
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(URL,caps);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using ECLIPSE IDE. Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect import statement. Ideally, your program should use `import java.net.URL;` instead of `import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;`

I have posted the complete updated code snippet below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class sauceprog
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException
    {
        String browser = "safari-saucelabs";
        String URL = "https://<sauce_user>:<key>@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";
        DesiredCapabilities caps = null;

        switch(browser.toLowerCase())
        {
            case "internetexplorer-win-saucelabs":
                caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
                caps.setCapability("version", "11.103");
                caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
                caps.setCapability("screenResolution", "1024x768");
                break;
            case "chrome-win-saucelabs":
                caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8");
                caps.setCapability("version", "69.0");
                caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
                break;
            case "firefox-win-saucelabs":
                caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8");
                caps.setCapability("version", "62.0");
                caps.setCapability("recordVideo", "false");
            default:
                System.out.println("you passed incorrect values. Please check next time");
        }
        RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL),caps);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Also, I would suggest you update your sauce username and key if not already done. Since you posted the username and key publicly, anyone can run their tests on your account using the same.